# Android - URI Scheme - Stop from opening multiple instances of application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, uri

I'm using a custom URI scheme to redirect the user from a website to the application, but when launching the app, it opens a new instance instead of just restoring the already open one.

I have tried both using launchMode="singleTask" or "singleInstance" but they don't seem to affect it.

```
<!-- Splash. -->
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"

        android:name=".Activities.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="customscheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Example:

1. User opens the application, from Activity A goes to Activity B .
2. User opens website, and gets redirected back to app via URI.
3. Application is now on Activity A.
4. User presses back button, destroying Activity A.
5. Activity B is now present from first instance.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: first: check if you don't have "do not keep activities" checked ... second: *it opens a new instance instead...* how you are so sure about this?

Comment: Where would "Do not keep activities" be checked? And because when using the application, pressing the back button to close the application simply closing ones, and shows another one still under it.

Comment: it is some programmer/debugging option ... still you wrote thet activity b appear ... is the activity a "under" it?

Comment: Activity B from the first run is under Activity A from the second run.

Comment: what if you are wrong ... and this is activity a from first run just moved in front of Activity B ... that's why I'm asking why you are so sure ...

Comment: I am 100% sure it's another instance of the same application.

Comment: And I'm 100% sure that it is the same ... I have more reputation ... I win ... again: **why** are you so sure? do you add some loggin (if so, where) ... ok real question should be: **why are you thinking that it is a different instance?**

Comment: Because my example was a dumbed down version of the application, and I've had more than 2 of the same instances in many different Activities of the application.  Are you trying to say it's the same instance, but multiple activities just stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81628/discussion-between-awestruck-and-selvin).

Comment: [It's working for me](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/c2053f4c1ddc66bb1ec8)

Comment: Please post the manifest entry for Activity B as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've not set `android:taskAffinity` for Activity B, this is doing the correct thing.

- When you launch the app it starts ActivityA
- ActivityA launches ActivityB into the same task (even if you set `launchMode="singleInstance"` for ActivityB, Android will ignore that since it has the same `taskAffinity` as ActivityA)
- User opens website and is redirected back to the app. Android brings the existing task for the application (containing ActivityA and ActivityB) to the foreground and creates a new instance of ActivityA and puts that on top of the existing activies. Now you have a task stack with ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityA.
- User presses the BACK button, which finishes the instance of ActivityA on top of the stack and reveals the instance of ActivityB underneath.

If you think about this, Android cannot open the existing instance of ActivityA because it is covered by ActivityB.

There are multiple ways of getting around this, depending on how you want your app to behave in different circumstances. Let's assume that, if the app is already running, you want the task stack to be cleared back to the root instance of ActivityA and you want to reuse that instance (and not create another one).  One of the easiest ways to do this is to have the web browser open another activity (not ActivityA), let's call it `RedirectActivity` . This new activity has the following code in its `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(...);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This code will do one of the following, depending...

1. If the app was not already running, it will create a new instance of ActivityA.
2. If the app was already running, it will clear the task stack of any activities that may be on top of the existing instance of ActivityA and then it will return to the existing instance of ActivityA.

NOTE: There are other behaviours that might be appropriate and other techniques that you can use to get similar behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was really easy to follow and I understood what you're saying. I used your RedirectActivity code and it works well. I'll have to look into it more to get a better behavior for what I want to do with it, but for now it works really well. Thank you again.